# Access a specific label based on a string

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I have 10 labels on an ASP.NET page, is there a way I can programatically choose one of the labels to set based on a value?

i.e.

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="errormsgLbl1" CssClass="errorMessage"/>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="errormsgLbl2" CssClass="errorMessage"/>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="errormsgLbl3" CssClass="errorMessage"/>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="errormsgLbl4" CssClass="errorMessage"/>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="errormsgLbl5" CssClass="errorMessage"/>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="errormsgLbl6" CssClass="errorMessage"/>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="errormsgLbl7" CssClass="errorMessage"/>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="errormsgLbl8" CssClass="errorMessage"/>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="errormsgLbl9" CssClass="errorMessage"/>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="errormsgLbl10" CssClass="errorMessage"/>
```

Then in my codebehind

```
var labeltochange = "errormsgLbl1";
.
. Magic here
.
labeltochange.text = "message";
```

Comment: If you can provide some more info on why you have 10 labels, we might be able to suggest a better approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`Control.FindControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) method:

```
var labeltochange = "errormsgLbl1";
Label label = (Label)this.FindControl(labeltochange);
label.Text = "message";
```

See [`How to: Access Server Controls By ID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y81z8326.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue why you are using string references in the first place, it would be better coding practice to use a strongly typed reference.

```
Label labeltochange;

if (some logic..){
  labeltochange = errormsgLbl1;
}
else (some other logic..){
  labeltochange = errormsgLbl2;
}
labeltochange.Text = "message";
```

---

`FindControl` is okay to use, but you'll get a null reference exception if you ever change the IDs in the markup without updating your code behind logic.

Whereas refering to them by the control itself will prevent compilation altogether.

Comment: The ID is the result of a concatenation so whilst your method is "better" it doesn't suit my situation.

Answer (score 2):

Use [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx):

> Searches the current naming container for a server control with the specified id parameter.
>   Use this to access a control that is inside another container, or in other circumstances where the target control is not directly accessible to the caller.

Here you go:

```
var labeltochange = "errormsgLbl1";

// Find control on page.
Label lbl = (Label)FindControl(labeltochange);  // Magic

lbl.Text = "message";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FindControl` method. So your code will look more like this:

```
Label labeltochange =(Label)tab.FindControl("errormsgLbl"+i);
```